# iOS: Crash when presenting a PageViewController in ViewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I'm working on an iPad app and I need to create a help window that pops up if the app's being started for the first time. To this end, I do a small check in viewDidLayoutSubViews(...) and then try to launch the help window thusly:

```
    [self getHelpImages];
    self.fPageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.fPageViewController.dataSource = self;
    PageContentViewController* startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.fPageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers
                                       direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                        animated:NO
                                      completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.fPageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);
    [self.fPageViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [self.fPageViewController setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];
    [self presentViewController:self.fPageViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Where 'fPageViewController' is of type UIPageViewController. The problem is that I get a crash, and I'm not sure why. My first suspicion was that fPageViewController was nil, but it's being instantiate at the top of the block. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Here is a snippet of the trace:

```
frame #9: 0x03f56448 CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
frame #10: 0x0246b23e Foundation`-[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
frame #11: 0x01312e8b UIKit`-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 192
frame #12: 0x0108b78c UIKit`-[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 6433
frame #13: 0x0108bcaf UIKit`-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 130
frame #14: 0x00016bb8 Bones`-[ViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews](self=0x0ba29400, _cmd=0x016e943b) + 27288 at ViewController.mm:1158
```

Comment: What's the error from the crash? It's not appropriate to display another view controller from the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. Instead, add a check in the app delegate. If it's the first launch of the app, present the help window from the root view controller.

Comment: Normally you should post crash log and message when asking such question.

Comment: Also `viewDidLoad` is much better place to present something at start.

Comment: Nothing happens if it's in viewDidLoad (i.e. no crash, the app just starts). How do I get a trace from XCode? EDIT: Found out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like we should be using viewDidAppear for this. Moving the code there worked perfectly.